# Touchpad doesn't work but is recognized. After modprobe, it works but isn't recognized

Tags: 12.04, touchpad, synaptics, modprobe

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and my touchpad does not work. I've already tried some fixes that I found but none of them worked perfectly. Right now, the touchpad is recognized. `xinput list` gives me this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]    
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

And synclient returns this:

```
Parameter settings:
LeftEdge                = 100
RightEdge               = 2408
TopEdge                 = 71
BottomEdge              = 1249
FingerLow               = 1
FingerHigh              = 1
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 124
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 56
HorizScrollDelta        = 56
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 1
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 0
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0706
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 226
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 0
RBCornerButton          = 0
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 0
TapButton2              = 0
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.100007
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 0
PalmMinWidth            = 10
PalmMinZ                = 200
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 0
HorizHysteresis         = 14
VertHysteresis          = 14
ClickPad                = 0
```

The **Touchpad** tab on **Mouse and Touchpad** shows up, and Synaptiks work. But the touchpad doesn't work. The mouse barely moves, and when it does it just teleports randomly through the screen.

Now if I type in the terminal

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

The mouse works almost perfectly. It moves normally, I can click with the buttons, tap, etc. But I can't configure it. After typing the commands on terminal, this is my xinput list:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Synclient does not returns anything at all. Not even a single error message.

The **Mouse and Touchpad** settings is missing the **Touchpad** tab. And I get an internal error when trying to open Synaptiks.

I don't know why this happens. I've screwed some stuff up from trying some random solutions, so I figured I'd try to ask for help here. I wanted to make, at least, vertical edge scrolling work and disable tap clicking.

Some pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact same situation with an Elantech Touchpad too, and I was able to narrow it down to the fact the my XServer and its corresponding module (driver) did not support that Touchpad correctly.

The problem was solved by updating my kernel to 3.11 by updating UBUNTU to 12.04.4.

[This thread on Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2198715&highlight=) has details.

So assuming you are not on the fresh kernel, just update to the 12.04.4 [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) to solve the issue.